# How to convert a Postgres query table to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, postgresql, api

As a result of joining three tables in PostgreSQL in a query inside an API path operation function, I generate a table with this kind of structure:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_name | feature_name | feature_value | ingredient_name | ingredient_proportion |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_A    | feature_1    | 1.5           | ingredient_1    | 0.3                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_A    | feature_1    | 1.5           | ingredient_2    | 0.7                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_A    | feature_2    | 3.2           | ingredient_1    | 0.3                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_A    | feature_2    | 3.2           | ingredient_2    | 0.7                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_1    | 2.0           | ingredient_1    | 0.2                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_1    | 2.0           | ingredient_2    | 0.3                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_1    | 2.0           | ingredient_3    | 0.5                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_2    | 4.1           | ingredient_1    | 0.2                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_2    | 4.1           | ingredient_2    | 0.3                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
| dish_B    | feature_2    | 4.1           | ingredient_3    | 0.5                   |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
```

I would like that the path operation function returns a list of dictionaries which provides the information contained in the table. So something like this:

```
[{"dish_name": dish_A, 
  "feature_names": [feature_1, feature_2],
  "feature_values": [1.5, 3.2],
  "ingredient_names": [ingredient_1, ingredient_2],
  "ingredient_proportions": [0.3, 0.7]},
 {"dish_name": dish_B, 
  "feature_names": [feature_1, feature_2],
  "feature_values": [2.0, 4.1],
  "ingredient_names": [ingredient_1, ingredient_2, ingredient_3],
  "ingredient_proportions": [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]}]
```

How to do it in Python?

Comment: Looks like you can use the `psycopg2.extras` module as explained by this guy https://varun-verma.medium.com/use-psycopg2-to-return-dictionary-like-values-key-value-pairs-4d3047d8de1b

Comment: Does something like : `[dict(row.items()) for row in curr.execute(sqlText, params).fetchall()]` work?

Comment: @JonSG, that will not work if for no other reason then the OP is looking to aggregate values for given column/key e.g. `"feature_names": [feature_1, feature_2],`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are retrieving the data with `cursor.fetchall()`, here is a simple loop to aggregate dish data.

```py
def aggregate_dishes(rows: list[tuple]) -> list[dict[str, Any]]:
    """Aggregate dishes by dish name."""
    out = {}
    for dish, feature, value, ingredient, proportion in rows:
        if dish not in out:
            out[dish] = {
                "dish_name": dish,
                "feature_names": [],
                "feature_values": [],
                "ingredient_names": [],
                "ingredient_proportions": [],
            }
        out[dish]["feature_names"].append(feature)
        out[dish]["feature_values"].append(value)
        out[dish]["ingredient_names"].append(ingredient)
        out[dish]["ingredient_proportions"].append(proportion)
    return list(out.values())
```

Or if you want to do it directly in the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(dish) AS dishes
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_build_object(
          'dish_name', dish_name,
          'feature_names', jsonb_agg(feature_name),
          'feature_values', jsonb_agg(feature_value),
          'ingredient_names', jsonb_agg(ingredient_name),
          'ingredient_proportions', jsonb_agg(ingredient_proportion)
        ) AS dish
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY
        dish_name
) t
```